# How to pass object in NSInvocationOpreation

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, nsinvocationoperation

I have created an NSInvocationOpertion object as follows

```
NSString *myString = @"Jai Hanuman";
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(taskMethod) object:myString];
NSOperationQueue *operatioQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [operatioQueue addOperation:operation];
```

and can anybody tell me how can I access the myString object in taskMethod? Is it possible?

```
- (void)taskMethod{
    NSLog(@"Oh! Invocation's working buck");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Change your method to:

```
- (void)taskMethod:(NSString *) message{
NSLog(@"Oh! Invocation's working buck");
        message=//your string object;
  }
```

and

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(taskMethod:) object:myString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the method with one parameter:

```
- (void)taskMethod: (NSString *)theString {
    NSLog(@"Called with string: %@", theString);
}
```

and create the operation as:

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
         selector:@selector(taskMethod:) object:myString];
```

Note the additional colon in the selector, it indicates that the method
takes one argument.